# Using a macro + IF formula + static date?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I've only just started using Excel so am a bit of a newbie - please excuse my ignorance/lack of proper terminology!

I currently have column E, where people will manually enter a 'Y' to flag certain accounts. Once these accounts have been flagged, I have a macro button to change all these Y's to 'Flagged', so that I know they've been dealt with.

I wanted column F to add in the date that these were flagged, so I have an IF formula to say that if 'Raised' is in colE, add in today's date in colF. I was having issues with 2 things, firstly I need it to ignore any that already have a date in colF (as I don't want old dates overridden), and I didn't know how to 'freeze' the date. Currently, any time I open the worksheet it changes all the old dates to todays date, but I need to keep whatever the date was at the time it was entered.

All of my excel is self taught through reading forums (so please forgive me if this is terrible!), but at the moment I've come up with this:

```
Sub ResetFlags()
'
' ResetFlags Macro
'

'
Sheets("Matrix").Select
Columns("E:E").Select
Range("E2").Activate
Selection.Replace What:="y", Replacement:="Flagged", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Range("E12").Select

Dim r As Range
Set r = Range("F:F").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
On Error Resume Next
r.Formula = "=IF((RC[-1]=""Flagged""),(TODAY()),"""")"
On Error Resume Next

End Sub
```

The macro seems to work well in that it replaces the Y's with 'Flagged', it skips old dates and add today's date.. BUT every time I open the workbook it changes ALL the dates to today. How to I freeze the date?!

Also, when I run the macro, although it all runs through at the very end I get an error box saying 'Run-time error 1004: No cells were found'. I can't figure this out/how to get rid of it.

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

Think this should do it. You can replace the formula with the value so that it won't continually update.

The On Error should go before the the SpecialCells - if there are no blanks there is no range to which the formula can be applied, hence the error.

Also, no need to Select anything.

I havn't tested this so no surprises if it doesn't work first time.

```
Sub ResetFlags()

With Sheets("Matrix").Columns("E:E")
    .Replace What:="y", Replacement:="Flagged", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False

    Dim r As Range

    On Error Resume Next
    Set r = .Range("F:F").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    On Error GoTo 0
End With

If Not r Is Nothing Then
    r.Formula = "=IF((RC[-1]=""Flagged""),(TODAY()),"""")"
    r.Value = r.Value
End If

End Sub
```